# Pandas - Append rows to DataFrames as elements in a list, not working

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a list of dataframes that looks like this:

```
mylist=[pd.DataFrame({'a':[5,5],'b':[5,5]}),pd.DataFrame({'a':[6,6],'b':[6,6]})]
```

and a separate datframe (df) that I want to append to the bottom of the two dataframes in mylist.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[9],'b':[9]})
```

When I append by looping over mylist, the append works on the element of the list, but it does not update or change mylist.

```
for i in mylist:
    i=i.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    print(i, '\n')
    print(mylist, '\n')

   a  b
0  5  5
1  5  5
2  9  9 

[   a  b
 0  5  5
 1  5  5,
    a  b
 0  6  6
 1  6  6] 

    a  b
 0  6  6
 1  6  6
 2  9  9 

[   a  b
 0  5  5
 1  5  5,
    a  b
 0  6  6
 1  6  6]
```

I have tried multiple ways around this by using concat and by merging on 'a' and I get the same general result-- the dataframe elements are modified within the loop, but after the loop finishes nothing has changed.

When I try to make the same changes but without using a loop, then mylist *is* updated.

```
mylist[0]=mylist[0].append(df, ignore_index=True)
print(mylist[0])
print(mylist)

   a  b
0  5  5
1  5  5
2  9  9

[   a  b
 0  5  5
 1  5  5
 2  9  9,
    a  b
 0  6  6
 1  6  6]
```

Can someone please explain why this behavior happens in the for loop?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

#### `append` is not an `inplace` operation.

Refer to the indices of the list and modify the positions

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = mylist[i].append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: so I'm clear that I understand... I knew append was not an inplace operation, which is why I had the assignment statement in the loop.  What your solution suggests is that the fact that it's not an inplace operation applies to the container, i.e, mylist, and not just the element?

Comment: Correct.  In your loop, `i` was the object.  When you assigned `i = i.append(...` you overwrote the name `i` and **not** what is at that position in `mylist`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `append`: If you want to use `pd.concat` your input has to be a sequence of `pandas`objects

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = pd.concat([mylist[i], df])     # Passing the two dataframes as list, note the []
```